# Converting file text to Hashtable and reading value using keys?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-5.0

So I have a file that looks like :

```
A=www.google.com
B=www.yahoo.com
```

Now, I want to convert this text file to a HashTable and read values using keys ie A or B

This is what I have come up with:

```
$hash = Get-Content .\test.txt
$hash[1].Split('=')[1]
```

The above script works fine except that I want to use key instead of number

Something like :

```
$hash['B'].Split('=')[1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to convert the file data into a hashtable object first. There are several techniques to add data to a hashtable object. The following will convert all lines to a hash table value provided they have the format `key=value`.

```
$hash = [ordered]@{}
Get-Content test.txt | Foreach-Object {
    $key,$value = ($_ -split '=',2).Trim()
    $hash[$key] = $value
}

# Value Retrieval syntax
$hash.A
$hash['A']
```

If you want to target a specific line in the file, you can do the following:

```
$hash = [ordered]@{}
$data = Get-Content test.txt
$temp = $data[1] -split '=' 
$hash[$temp[0]] = $temp[1]

# Value Retrieval Syntax
$hash.B
$hash['B']
```

---

You could technically convert the file data with two commands, but the order may vary. I'm not sure if `ConvertFrom-StringData` is favorable anymore.

```
$hash = Get-Content test.txt -Raw | ConvertFrom-StringData

# Value Retrieval Syntax
$hash.B
$hash['B']
```

---

**Output From First Code Snippet:**

> ```
> Get-Content test.txt
> A=www.google.com
> B=www.yahoo.com
>
> $hash = [ordered]@{}
> Get-Content test.txt | Foreach-Object {
>     $temp = ($_ -split '=').Trim()
>     $hash[$temp[0]] = $temp[1]
> }
> $hash
>
> Name                           Value
> ----                           -----
> A                              www.google.com
> B                              www.yahoo.com
>
> $hash['B']
> www.yahoo.com
> ```

Comment: Doen't work. It works only when you hardcode the value inside @{} in script.

Comment: @SamuraiJack, I just added an output from running it on my console. I'd like to know what doesn't work for you. Which PowerShell version are you running because you have tagged several versions?

Comment: btw could you please tell me why `git clone <path>` works but `git clone $path` doesnt?

Comment: Nicely done; `ConvertFrom-StringData` is here to stay, `ConvertFrom-String` is not (was never ported to PS Core). Instead of using a `$temp` array, perhaps a conceptually clearer solution is to use`$key, $value = ($_ -split '=', 2).Trim()`